aiogram bot TelegramNetworkError: HTTP Client says - Request timeout error
I have a simple bot with start command handler:
@user_router.message(CommandStart())
async def start_command(message: Message):
    logger.info(f'Start from user {message.from_user.username} id={message.from_user.id}')
    await message.answer('Hello')


When I run the bot, I get the usual normal logs:
[2024-07-29 20:04:09,944] #INFO     bot.py:21 - __main__ - Starting bot
[2024-07-29 20:04:10,731] #INFO     dispatcher.py:527 - aiogram.dispatcher - Start polling
[2024-07-29 20:04:11,034] #INFO     dispatcher.py:341 - aiogram.dispatcher - Run polling for bot .... 

And after I press the start command - I get an error aiogram.exceptions.TelegramNetworkError: HTTP Client says - Request timeout error:
[2024-07-29 20:04:15,519] #INFO     user_handlers.py:23 - handlers.user_handlers - Start from user .....
[2024-07-29 20:05:15,969] #INFO     dispatcher.py:172 - aiogram.event - Update id=.... is not handled. Duration 60449 ms by bot id=....
[2024-07-29 20:05:15,970] #ERROR    dispatcher.py:315 - aiogram.event - Cause exception while process update id=..... by bot id=....
TelegramNetworkError: HTTP Client says - Request timeout error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/andreisukhar/Projects/Python/rulebreakers/she-bot/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/aiogram/client/session/aiohttp.py", line 181, in make_request
    async with session.post(
  File "/Users/andreisukhar/Projects/Python/rulebreakers/she-bot/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 1197, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/andreisukhar/Projects/Python/rulebreakers/she-bot/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 507, in _request
    with timer:
  File "/Users/andreisukhar/Projects/Python/rulebreakers/she-bot/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/aiohttp/helpers.py", line 735, in __exit__
    raise asyncio.TimeoutError from None
TimeoutError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/andreisukhar/Projects/Python/rulebreakers/she-bot/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py", line 309, in _process_update
    response = await self.feed_update(bot, update, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/andreisukhar/Projects/Python/rulebreakers/she-bot/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py", line 158, in feed_update
    response = await self.update.wrap_outer_middleware(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/andreisukhar/Projects/Python/rulebreakers/she-bot/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/middlewares/error.py", line 25, in __call__
    return await handler(event, data)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/andreisukhar/Projects/Python/rulebreakers/she-bot/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/middlewares/user_context.py", line 49, in __call__
    return await handler(event, data)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/andreisukhar/Projects/Python/rulebreakers/she-bot/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/aiogram/fsm/middleware.py", line 42, in __call__
    return await handler(event, data)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/andreisukhar/Projects/Python/rulebreakers/she-bot/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/event/telegram.py", line 121, in trigger
    return await wrapped_inner(event, kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/andreisukhar/Projects/Python/rulebreakers/she-bot/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/event/handler.py", line 43, in call
    return await wrapped()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/andreisukhar/Projects/Python/rulebreakers/she-bot/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py", line 276, in _listen_update
    return await self.propagate_event(update_type=update_type, event=event, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/andreisukhar/Projects/Python/rulebreakers/she-bot/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/router.py", line 142, in propagate_event
    return await observer.wrap_outer_middleware(_wrapped, event=event, data=kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/andreisukhar/Projects/Python/rulebreakers/she-bot/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/router.py", line 137, in _wrapped
    return await self._propagate_event(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/andreisukhar/Projects/Python/rulebreakers/she-bot/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/router.py", line 170, in _propagate_event
    response = await router.propagate_event(update_type=update_type, event=event, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/andreisukhar/Projects/Python/rulebreakers/she-bot/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/router.py", line 142, in propagate_event
    return await observer.wrap_outer_middleware(_wrapped, event=event, data=kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/andreisukhar/Projects/Python/rulebreakers/she-bot/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/router.py", line 137, in _wrapped
    return await self._propagate_event(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/andreisukhar/Projects/Python/rulebreakers/she-bot/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/router.py", line 162, in _propagate_event
    response = await observer.trigger(event, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/andreisukhar/Projects/Python/rulebreakers/she-bot/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/event/telegram.py", line 121, in trigger
    return await wrapped_inner(event, kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/andreisukhar/Projects/Python/rulebreakers/she-bot/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/event/handler.py", line 43, in call
    return await wrapped()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/andreisukhar/Projects/Python/rulebreakers/she-bot/handlers/user_handlers.py", line 31, in start_command
    await message.answer(LEXICON_RU['greeting'])
  File "/Users/andreisukhar/Projects/Python/rulebreakers/she-bot/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/aiogram/methods/base.py", line 84, in emit
    return await bot(self)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/andreisukhar/Projects/Python/rulebreakers/she-bot/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/aiogram/client/bot.py", line 485, in __call__
    return await self.session(self, method, timeout=request_timeout)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/andreisukhar/Projects/Python/rulebreakers/she-bot/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/aiogram/client/session/base.py", line 254, in __call__
    return cast(TelegramType, await middleware(bot, method))
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/andreisukhar/Projects/Python/rulebreakers/she-bot/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/aiogram/client/session/aiohttp.py", line 186, in make_request
    raise TelegramNetworkError(method=method, message="Request timeout error")
aiogram.exceptions.TelegramNetworkError: HTTP Client says - Request timeout error

I asked my friend to run on his computer - he has everything working and gets a response from the bot.
What could it be?

I've got the same problem on my VDS server. If I got 3+ working polling bots at same time AND these bots are using requests\aiohttp requests - this exception pops up quite frequently.
If you got more than 1 working bot\parser\etc. - consider using webhooks for bot. Works MUCH more stable.
